# Transient not behaving as expected

Tags: wp-query, transient

I am setting up some transients to reduce load with multiple custom WP_Query objects.

When I set the transient to expire within an hour for example, any change to a post / custom post is instantly reflected in the results within the loop utilizing the transient. According to my understanding the query should have been cached and the updated post values should only reflect after the specified time?

The transient is not set again, and works as expected in terms of the expiration time, it's just that the post changes are immediately available?

Or is my understanding of transients simply wrong?

A basic example below:

```
if ( false === ( $testimonial_loop = get_transient( 'testimonials' ) ) ) {

        $args = array(
            'post_type'     => 'testimonial',   
        );

        $testimonial_loop = new WP_Query( $args );        

    set_transient( 'testimonials', $testimonial_loop, 5 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

rule of thumb is probably to use transients for simple objects (strings integers, array) as the result of unserialization of objects might be surprising and side effect might happen unless the object is fully static.

IIRC, when unserializing an object PHP will also run its default constructor, which in your case will do the query again as unserialization is being done when it is retrieved from the DB.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and I understand, but why would the Codex list WP_Query as a specific example if the query is simply run again? Would there be any benefit to caching a query such as this as numerous examples use cached WP queries specifically?

Comment: I am obviously guessing, and if you can provide link to the codex I will look again, but generally php object serialization and unserialization is source for surprises (and I only understand the concept of the "why" not all the details)

Comment: Ok cool, please see the last example below [https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API)

Comment: OK, so now you also know that the codex examples can not be trusted ;). Frankly I don't see the point of caching a query, as posts might not exist anymore when you process it (assuming that code did work as expected...) it makes much more sense to compute the HTML and cache it.